# Adding mathematical constraints to ODE integration

Tags: python, constraints, ode

I'm working with a modified Hodgkin-Huxley equation (mainly to verify the equation gives good results), and the integration seems to have a slight problem. Basically, the system is defined with a bunch of "states" and the equation does the calculation based on the fraction of neuron channels in each state. Mathematically, what this means is that (a) the fraction of each channel should be between 0 and 1, and (b) the sum of the fraction of states should be 1. I would like to add these constraints to my equation integration. The code is here:

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

def alpham(V):
    out =  0.1 * (25-V) / (sp.exp((25-V)/10)-1)
    return out

def betam(V):
    out = 4 * sp.exp(-V/18)
    return out

def alphah(V):
    out =  0.07 * sp.exp(-V/20)
    return out

def betah(V):
    out = 1 / (sp.exp((30-V)/10)+1)
    return out

def alphan(V):
    out = 0.01 * (10-V) / (sp.exp((10-V)/10)-1)
    return out

def betan(V):
    out = 0.125 * sp.exp(-V/80)
    return out

dt=0.01
T = sp.arange(0.0, 100.0, dt)
nt = len(T)  # total number of time steps

# Define global variables
C = 1 # Capacitance (muF /cm**2)
gNa = 120 # Maximimal Na conductance (mS/cm**2)
ENa = 115 # Na reversal potential (mV)
gK = 36 # Maximal K conductance (mS/cm**2)
EK = -12 # K reversal potential (mV)
gL = 0.3 # Leak conductance (mS/cm**2)
EL = 10.6 # Leak reversal potential (mV)

ANa = lambda V: np.array(( (-3*alpham(V)-alphah(V), betam(V), 0, 0, betah(V), 0, 0, 0),
                (3*alpham(V),-2*alpham(V)-betam(V)-alphah(V), 2*betam(V), 0, 0, betah(V), 0, 0),
                (0, 2*alpham(V), -alpham(V)-2*betam(V)-alphah(V), 3*betam(V), 0, 0, betah(V), 0),
                (0, 0, alpham(V), -3*betam(V)-alphah(V), 0, 0, 0, betah(V)),
                (alphah(V), 0, 0, 0, -3*alpham(V)-betah(V), betam(V), 0, 0),
                (0, alphah(V), 0, 0, 3*alpham(V), -2*alpham(V)-betam(V)-betah(V), 2*betam(V), 0),
                (0, 0, alphah(V), 0, 0, 2*alpham(V), -alpham(V)-2*betam(V)-betah(V), 3*betam(V)),
                (0, 0, 0, alphah(V), 0, 0, alpham(V), -3*betam(V)-betah(V)) ))

            # Drift K
AK = lambda V: np.array(( (-4*alphan(V), betan(V), 0, 0, 0),
                (4*alphan(V), -3*alphan(V)-betan(V), 0, 0, 0),
                (0, 3*alphan(V), -2*alphan(V)-2*betan(V), 3*betan(V), 0),
                (0, 0, 2*alphan(V), -alphan(V)-3*betan(V), 4*betan(V)),
                (0, 0, 0, alphan(V), -4*betan(V)) ))

def I_Na(V,y): return gNa*y[7]*(V-ENa)
def I_K(V,x): return gK*x[4]*(V-EK)
def I_L(V): return gL*(V-EL)
def I_inj(t): return 10.0

V = np.zeros((nt))
X = np.zeros((nt,5))
Y = np.zeros((nt,8))

X[:,0] = 1
Y[:,0] = 1

#Integration
for i in range(1,nt):
    V[i] = V[i-1]+dt*(I_inj(i-1)-I_Na(V[i-1],Y[i-1])-I_K(V[i-1],X[i-1])-I_L(V[i-1]))
    X[i] = X[i-1]+dt*np.dot(AK(V[i-1]),X[i-1])
    Y[i] = Y[i-1]+dt*np.dot(ANa(V[i-1]),Y[i-1])

plt.plot(T,V,'red', label='Fox and Lu')
plt.legend()
```

X is a nt x 5 vector (nt for time, 5 for the 5 states of the Potassium channels), and similarly Y is nt x 8. So for example, each state component of X should be between 0 and 1 for each time point, and the sum of the states should be 1 at each time point (and the same for the Y matrix). How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Your question does not seem to be about programming but about choosing an algorithm. I suggest that you re-ask it on [scicomp.se] using mathematical equations to describe your problem instead of a lot of code that is difficult to read and most of which is not relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: I also strongly suggest that you do not use the Euler method for anything. More sophisticated, easy-to-use ODE integrators for Python exist.